# Arithmetic with PowerShell Timespans

Tags: powershell, timespan

PowerShell Timespans are great for quickly displaying durations, as in:

```
$starttime = $(get-date)
{ do some processing here }
write-host "Duration: $((new-timespan $starttime $(get-date)).tostring())"
```

But if I did `$loopcount` iterations of processing during that timeframe, how do I divide the duration by `$loopcount` to get the average duration per iteration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A slightly nicer way if doing this (if you don't need output from your script block) would probably be:

```
1..$loopcount | ForEach-Object {
    Measure-Command {
        # do some processing here
    }
} | Measure-Object -Average TotalSeconds
```

Comment: Great answer -- I gave this a slight edge over the other answer based on personal aesthetics.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, you can tweak as needed.

```
$StartTime = Get-Date
{ <#do some processing here#> }

$TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan $StartTime (Get-Date)
$AverageTimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Seconds ($TimeSpan.TotalSeconds / $LoopCount)
```

Seconds is the best unit to use for this.

Comment: Great answer -- I wish I could award two answers

Comment: You know, it isn't that great afterall.  It isn't truely measuring each iteration, just estimating.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried to add this as a comment, but the formatting of the code was just to limited in the comment, so I'll make it as another answer.

I had a similar need, but I was looping over a collection and needing to measure 2 different operations on each element in the collection and wanted to sum up the total time it took for each operation.

Here is what I did:

```
$opATot = New-TimeSpan
$opBTot = New-TimeSpan
$myData | %{
   $opA = Measure-Command -Expression { do-op-a $_ }
   $opB = Measure-Command -Expression { do-op-b $_ }
   $opATot = $opATot.add( $opA )
   $opBTot = $opBTot.add( $opB )
}
"Op A took " + $opATot
"Op B took " + $opBTot
```

Comment: You could add to this pattern by counting the number of iterations made and then performing the average calculations at the end by dividing the total seconds by the loop count.